# Cannot find clang-format in FreeBSD 11.2

Tags: freebsd, clang-format

I installed a FreeBSD virtual machine and then I ran `sudo pkg install clang-devel`.

`clang-format` seems to be missing however:

> -sh: clang-format: not found

How to install `clang-format` in FreeBSD 11.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may look at the files installed by the `clang-devel` package (for example on [FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/devel/llvm-devel/)).

I can see a couple of files which might be the one you are looking for:

- `bin/clang-format-devel`
- `llvm-devel/bin/clang-format`

They are installed under `/usr/local` by default.

Alternatively, you may use the [advanced search feature on FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/search.php). Here's the link to the search result for *clang-format* in pkg-plists (pkg-plist is a file with a list of files installed by a package): https://www.freshports.org/search.php?stype=pkg-plist&method=match&query=clang-format&num=100&orderby=category&orderbyupdown=asc&search=Search&format=html&branch=head

It's worth noting that there is no easy way to do it with [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) or [ports(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) as some packages generate their *pkg-plists* dynamically. This is why the easiest solution is to use external services like [FreshPorts](https://www.freshports.org/). There is also a plugin for [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) called [pkg-provides](https://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/pkg-provides/) available in the FreeBSD ports tree, which might be what you are looking for. I've never tried it, however.